# Go access pointer value if its passed as interface{}

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I'm writing a program where I need to access a value of a pointer which is passed as an `interface{}`.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ufpwtc7kMe)

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

type Test struct {
    Names []string
}

func main() {
    arr := []string{"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}
    obj := new(Test)
    obj.Names = arr
    TestFunc(obj)   
}

func TestFunc(obj interface{}){
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(obj)
    switch rt.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            return
        case reflect.Ptr:
            TestFunc(*obj)  //<<--- There is the problem, cannot figure out how to access 
//value of obj and *obj is not allowed here because of interface{} type.
    }
}
```

This is just a sample from a much bigger program, but it is enough to explain my problem.

So the problem is, when I pass a pointer to `TestFunc()` I do not know how to reach its value inside function. Is it possible at all?

I need to do some stuff based on wether it is a pointer or not, so if I keep passing pointer recursively the program will fail. I need to get the value from the passed pointer(and pass forward value instead of pointer) but I am not sure if it is possible because I am dealing with a type `interface{}` and not a pointer and compiler does not know if it is going to be a pointer passed so it does not allow something like "*obj" to reach the value of it.

Comment: Do you really need reflect here, or are you just looking for a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) or [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches)?

Comment: Actually yes, because here is just a sample of actual program, I need to access the field names and values later. Of course I might be missing something, I just started using Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to support arbitrary levels of pointers then you can use reflection to get the value object:

```
v:=reflect.ValueOf(obj)
for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.Elem()
}
v.Interface()
```

However, this is quite unusual to actually need to do in practice.

For your function, this could work as something like:

```
func TestFunc(obj interface{}){
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(obj)
    switch rv.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            // code here
            return
        case reflect.Ptr:
            TestFunc(rv.Elm().Interface()) 
    }
}
```